# How to set up variables in multi-part cloud-init userdata scripts?

Tags: cloud-init

I want to be able to set a variable in a `shell-script` - which is part of a multi-part cloud-init userdata configuration setup, and use this variable in a `cloud-config` script that comes later in the multi-part userdata.

Is this possible to do? An example would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use a file. Set the "variable" with `echo "value" > /tmp/myvar` and get it with `` echo `cat /tmp/myvar` ``.

Comment: A cloud config script cannot run echo to fetch a variable like this, right?

Comment: The echo in this case is just an example of a command using that variable. A more accurate example might be a variable named "doTheThing". You could set the value with `echo "true" > /tmp/doTheThing` and test for it using ``if `cat /tmp/doTheThing`; then do a thing; fi``

Comment: It doesn't support variables, but is a great workaround!